# Cannot import modul in tests file

Tags: python, django

Hi I have strange problem cause when I'm trying to import models to my test file I'm receiving error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Book'

[image]

module exist cause I have copied & paste it from another file.

My models code:

```
from django.db import models
from isbn_field import ISBNField
from Book.validators import page_validator, date_validator

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)    
    publication_date = models.CharField(validators=[date_validator,], max_length=10)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField("Author", related_name="author")
    ISBN = ISBNField() #validators=[book_unique_validator,]
    pages = models.IntegerField(validators=[page_validator,], blank=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=4)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_all_authors(self):
        return "".join([x.name.title() +", " for x in self.authors.all()])[:-2]

    class Meta:
         ordering = ["title"]
```

My test code:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from Book.models import Book, Author


class BookAPITestCase(TestCase):

    def create(self):
        author_obj = Author.create(
        name="test author"
        )
        book_obj = Book.create(
            title="Test_title",
            publication_date="2019-11-20",
            authors=author_obj,
            ISBN="9788381107419",
            pages=295,
            language="en"
        )

    def test_author(self):
        author_count = Author.objects.count()
        self.assertEqual(author_count, 1)
```

Ps. I have tried several different import variations like:
from Book.models 
from models
from .models
None of them worked in this one file.

Comment: It looks like you have set your `PYTHONPATH` in the `Book` or `Book/tests` directory, but it should be at the root of the models. Furthermore you better run the tests through `python3 manage.py test`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/overview/

Comment: I have moved my code to tests folder inside my Book folder and with command "manage.py test Book.tests" it start working, what took me a some time to start working.